# I can't use commas in android programming with java

Tags: android

I am developing an application for a calculation. I cannot use the period or comma marks on the keyboard. What do you think is the reason?

I am sharing some of the code structure I have written. This will be self explanatory.

```
    Package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHesapla);
        final EditText birincisayi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBirinciSayi);
        final EditText ikincisayi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtIkinciSayi);

        final TextView label1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);



        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                double sayi1 = Double.parseDouble(birincisayi.getText().toString());
                double sayi2 = Double.parseDouble(ikincisayi.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Can you paste an sample code? I am assume you have the basic of Java?

Comment: Check the InputType attribute value of EditText field

Comment: I am sharing some of the code structure I have written. This will be self explanatory.

Comment: `This will be self explanatory.` well, you've missed out the part which is most likely making a difference, the xml :)

Comment: You are right. I solved the problem by editing the xlm structure. Previously, it was android:inputType="number". I changed the input type to "numberDecimal" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no way for any app to do that.  The keyboard is a separate application, and not part of the OS.  It decides what keys to show.  You can give it a hint using the input type, but it gets final say.  To end that hint, set the input type of the edit text in the xml.

As an aside, I don't know any keyboard that shows a comma with a numbers field.  Its just not commonly done.

Comment: Previously, it was android:inputType="number". I changed the input type to "numberDecimal" and the problem was solved.